# Echo a Bell Character Cmd

Tags: cmd, control-characters

At the command prompt in Windows, I can echo a bell character by typing `echo` and then holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to produce `echo ^G`, and it will make a bell noise when I run it.

When I actually type `echo ^G` with my keyboard, it will only print `G` onto the screen and not make any noise.

Can someone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: `BEL` is ASCII Code `7` (`0x07`), which isn't a displayable character. `^G` is just a representation on the Screen to let humans know. The displayed string consists of two characters: `^ `=`0x5E` and `G`=`0x47`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ^G in the first case is supposed to represent one character which is the Ctrl-G character.

When you are typing ^G you are typing two characters and they are interpreted as two characters.

However the command line treats ^ as a special character to let it know that the next character is to be treated literally, so it is not actually displayed on the screen, so you just see the G.

Comment: Is there a way to type the bell character in a batch file?

Comment: Depends on your editor. Sometimes holding down Alt and pressing 007 on the number pad will insert the character. Does not work with notepad, but if you type **Echo echo ^G > beep.cmd** (where ^G is Ctrl-G) then you can edit beep.cmd in notepad and cut and paste to where you need it.

Comment: Just to add on to @sgmoore 's comment, you can bypass the notepad by piping the output to your clipboard directly:   `echo {Ctrl+G} | clip`